# Can we make [gitconfig] a synonym for [git-config]?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

While editing some Git questions today, I noticed that we have two tags for configuring Git:

- [git-config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-config)
- [gitconfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gitconfig)

You could argue that the second one is supposed to represent a user's `.gitconfig` file, except that when you look at [the tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/gitconfig/info), it's clearly referring to the `git config` command:

> You can query/set/replace/unset options with this command. The name is actually the section and the key separated by a dot, and the value will be escaped.

I don't think it's necessary to have two separate tags for both the `git config` command and the `.gitconfig` file. They both deal with configuring Git.

Can `[gitconfig]` be made into a synonym for `[git-config]` please? The latter tag that uses the dash is more consistent with the other Git command tags.

Comment: `git config --global alias.gitconfig "git-config"`